# CKFInder Custom asp.net control error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckfinder, file-browser

Hello every one so i am trying to work wit the CKFinder 3.4 version updating the old version CKFinder 2.6 and old Version comes with a dll file named `CKFinder.dll` that comes with a control names Filebrowser that is used to create this Tag

```
<CKFinder:FileBrowser ID="FileBrowser1" BasePath="ckfinder/" Width="100%" runat="server" ></CKFinder:FileBrowser>
```

in ASP.NET now the new version comes with a dll file named `CKSource.FileSystem.dll` and now I am trying to make the same controller

```
 <CKSource:FileBrowser ID="FileBrowser1" BasePath="ckfinder/" Width="100%" runat="server" ></CKSource:FileBrowser>
```

using this

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKSource.FileSystem" Namespace="CKSource.FileSystem" TagPrefix="CKSource" %>
```

But it says error creating the Control unknown server tag. Am I using the wrong dll file here?

Comment: Older version tag is         <CKFinder:FileBrowser ID="FileBrowser1" BasePath="ckfinder/" Width="100%" runat="server" ></CKFinder:FileBrowser>
Sorry  made miss spellings some where there.

Answer (score 0):

CKFinder 3 is not backwards compatible with CKFinder 2. It is not enough to exchange one dll file. You need to install it **from scratch**. Also the Control is no longer available in CKFinder 3.x. Please see below links to get better idea of how new CKFinder should be installed:

- http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/system_requirements.html
- http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html
- http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html#quickstart_troubleshooting
- http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/integration.html
- http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/configuration.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply i Appreciate your time and interest. I did every thing on those links. I took out the old CkFinder 2.x and then i reinstalled the 3.x now the way i called CkFinder 2.x is by control and now CKFinder 3.x i cant find a way how to call in ASP.net Beside the control. How do i call the CKFinder 3.4x instead of the control.

Comment: Please see these two links: https://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/guide/dev_integration, http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/integration.html#integration_existing_application. You don't use Control. You use JavaScript and if you want to control CKFinder on server-side, please see this link: http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/configuration_by_code.html.